# Mix letters of a string in alphabetical order in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have the cell array of strings in matlab. I want to sort letters in every string in alphabetical order. How can I do that?

For example, if I have `['dcb','aetk','acb'}]`, I want it to be: `['bcd','aekt','abc']`.

Comment: Sort each string individually, or sort all the letters of all the strings into one output string? A brief example of the input and desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handy helper here is [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), with the correct option for nonscalar output - we tell it to run [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) on each element of the cell array in turn:

```
>> a = {'dcb' 'aetk' 'acb'}
a =
{
  [1,1] = dcb
  [1,2] = aetk
  [1,3] = acb
}

>> b = cellfun(@sort, a, 'UniformOutput', false);
b =
{
  [1,1] = bcd
  [1,2] = aekt
  [1,3] = abc
}
```