# How to number strings according to their order

Tags: string, matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have a cell array of strings in matlab. Some strings may be equal. I want to number strings in the lexicographical way.

For example, if I have `{'abc','aty','utf8','sport','utf8','abc'}`, in the output I want to get the array `[1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1]`.

Can you give me any approach?

Comment: You would do us a favour if you used correct Matlab syntax (this comment also applies to [a previous question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284076/mix-letters-of-a-string-in-alphabetical-order-in-matlab)): `{'abc','aty'}` etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duplicated strings make using `sort` tricky, but in this case you can rely on the fact that [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) works for cell arrays of strings, and both sorts its output and optionally returns the indices of those sorted elements in the original input:

```
>> a = {'abc' 'aty' 'utf8' 'sport' 'utf8' 'abc'}
a =
{
  [1,1] = abc
  [1,2] = aty
  [1,3] = utf8
  [1,4] = sport
  [1,5] = utf8
  [1,6] = abc
}

>> [b, ~, index] = unique(a)
b =
{
  [1,1] = abc
  [1,2] = aty
  [1,3] = sport
  [1,4] = utf8
}
index =

   1   2   4   3   4   1
```

or you can obviously just use `[~, ~, index] = unique(a);` if you really *only* want the indices.

Comment: Unique without sorting has also been recently introduced. Just type, `unique(<<yourMat>>,'stable')`